# How to send formatted Rich Text Box as mail signature to some one in c# winform

Tags: c#, winforms, smtp, richtextbox, formatted-text

I have created an email signature using Rich Text Box. I want to sent this to my client through smtp protocol. I know the code to send smtp mail, but how to send [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5aLO.png) formatted text to the client as mail body?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the body to be formatted like your richtextbox text is formatted, you must write some logic in order to convert the text into html.
 when i say logic i mean that you must locate new lines, bold text, text color etc.. inside your richtextbox and convert it to html.
for example lets say that is the text inside your textbox:

> Hello
>  I AM **ROBOT**

you must write the logic in order to convert it to that string:

```
<span> Hello <br/> I AM <b>ROBOT</b></span>
```

after the text is embedded as `html` pass it to the `.Body` property of `MailMessage` class, also `.IsBodyHtml` property must be set to TRUE.
here is a a recommended tool for that task: [Writing Your Own RTF Converter](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27431/Writing-Your-Own-RTF-Converter) if you dont want to do it by yourself.

Comment: hi....i am facing a issue by using this method.its not allowing to convert and send embedded image

Comment: this is a completely different question. please publish a new question about you problem, maybe i can help you with this.

Comment: Sir I have already posted a question regarding this issue. but still no help. Please refer [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45052216/send-embedded-image-in-html-body-by-using-rich-textboxs-rtf-to-html-converter-m)

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is sending an email in html format:

```
MailMessage myMail = new MailMessage();    
myMail.IsBodyHtml = true;
myMail.Body = "<b>here your html text</b>";
```

Use the `System.Net.Mail` namespace.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It won't work that because I want to send formatted text which is on the Rich Text Box.